# How to display a loading html page while site content loads?

Tags: html

I am working on a site which contains a whole bunch of MP3s and images, which obviously got some loading time. I'd like to display a loading page while all the content loads.

I have no idea how to achieve this, but I do have the animated gif I want to use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've a suggestion google this, We don't write code for you we only help to learn from mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you make a preloader with 100% width and height of the viewport, set a background color and your GIF on it. What the following JS does, is wait until everything has loaded and then the preloader fades out.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('300', function(){
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        var $preloader = $('#page-preloader'),
        $spinner   = $preloader.find('.spinner');    

        $spinner.fadeOut();
        $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="page-preloader">
    <span class="spinner"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
tbody tr td{
    max-width: 300px;
}
h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.container>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#page-preloader {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #fff;
   z-index: 100500;
}
#page-preloader .spinner {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   background: url('YOUR-IMAGE-NAME.gif') no-repeat 50% 50%;
   margin: -16px 0 0 -16px;
}
```

Do not forget to add a JQuery to the project!