# HTML loading page spinner doesn't fade way

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was following this and more articles:

[How to display a loading html page while site content loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670009/how-to-display-a-loading-html-page-while-site-content-loads)

and this here: my favourite:

```
`https://codepen.io/mimoYmima/pen/fisgL`
```

My problem is that if I copy and paste it 1:1 my loading page doesn't fade away but if the site is already in cache it doesn't show it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable=no">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
      <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="keywords" content="">
      <meta name="Dexter" content="">
    
      <title>Code-Unknown</title>
      
      <!-- ============ GOOGLE FONTS ============ -->
      <link href='font-awesome/fonts/Raleway.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='font-awesome/fonts/Open+Sans.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link href='font-awesome/fonts/Iceberg.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
      <!-- CSS -->
      <!-- Animate css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
      <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
      <!-- Custom styles CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap v3.3.1 -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- Favicons -->
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/Code-Unknown.ico">
   <!-- Css 2.0 -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="client-login/assets/css/form-elements.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="client-login/assets/css/style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client-login/assets/css/sweetalert.css">
   
   <link href="assets/css/please-wait.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
   
           <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/ico/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="client-login/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="client-login/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="client-login/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="client-login/assets/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

 
  <body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="preloader"></div>


<!-- HEADER -->
<header id="top">
<canvas id="constellation"></canvas>
<div class="welcome">

    <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="190" height="190" alt=""> </div>

    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  
   <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 social-login">
    <div class="social-login-buttons">
                          
          <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="">
                            <i class="fa fa-steam"></i> Steam
                               </a>
          
                          <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="">
                          <i class="fa fa-server"></i> 
                          </a>
        
                          <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="">
                          <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> 
                          </a>
        
        <a class="btn btn-link-2" href="">
                          <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> 
                          </a>
        
                         </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<p> </p>         

        
         
</div>
</header>

<!-- END HEADER -->


<!-- END FOOTER -->

    <!-- Javascript files -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Backstretch -->
    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CountDown  -->
    <script src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <!-- Validate form -->
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <!-- Scroll Reveal -->
    <script src="js/scrollReveal.js"></script>
    <!-- Youtube Player -->
    <!-- Smooth-scroll -->
    <script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
    <!-- Ajax chimp -->
    <script src="js/jquery.ajaxchimp.js"></script>
    <!-- TweenLite -->
    <script src="js/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
    <!-- EasePack -->
    <script src="js/EasePack.min.js"></script>
    <!-- rAF -->
    <script src="js/rAF.js"></script>
    <!-- Constellation -->
    <script src="js/constellation.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <!-- right click off -->
 <script src="js/rightclickoff.js"></script>
 <!-- loading -->
 <script src="js/loading.js"></script>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post your html

Comment: can i upload it here somewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```js
$(function() { // waiting for the page to bo be fully loaded
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() { // fading out preloader
    $(this).remove(); // removing it from the DOM
  });
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  width: 100vw; /* viewport width */
  height: 100vh; /* viewport height. You can use percents, though. It requires your html and body to be 100% x 100% too */
  position: fixed;
  
  background: #333 url(http://files.mimoymima.com/images/loading.gif) center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="preloader"></div>
```

We also need your markup to narrow down your issue.

Comment: this is working even if the page is already in the cache but it still doesnt fade away

Comment: seems like you have some resources, that cannot be accessed and loaded to page. Check the console log for errors.

Comment: im sorry i have not a lot knowledge what console do you mean? java? and how do i access it ? webserver or client ?

Comment: Go to your page, in Chrome right-click on the page and select "Inspect", then usually at the bottom you'll see the white area labeled "Console". In your case it could contain red or yellow text with errors and warnings.

See the link https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: please-wait.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()scrollReveal.js:489 Mixed Content: The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/raleway/v10/PKCRbVvRfd5n7BTjtGiFZPk_vArhqVIZ0nv9q090hN8.woff2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
scrollY @ scrollReveal.js:489main.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at main.js:1
htclickoff.js

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()main.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[_0x5b7e[71]] is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:1) at j (jquery.js:2)at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2) at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)

Comment: ah, you have a bunch of errors to solve :). Firstly, insert a relevant path to "please-wait.css", because it's cannot be find on the server, then try to reload without cache. If not solved, you should look into solving the next error with your "main.js".

Comment: but i have no please wait css :S and i have no clue what these errors on my main.js say

Comment: Just post your html to your question, we should see it.

Comment: i added it to the post

Comment: Remove this line <link href="assets/css/please-wait.css" rel="stylesheet"> in your head tag and try to reload without cache. Also verify if all the files called in your html are accessible on server, your problem is there.

Comment: the page shows now the loader gif on a own page and i can scroll down to the normal page

Comment: I updated the answer, use updated CSS code. And what about your initial issue, is it solved?

Comment: Glad to know that :) And, please, accept the answer then.

Comment: there is one more thing that changed the site was mobile responsive but now on firefox mobile it shows the a extra site with the spinner and if i scroll down there is the normal one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152395/discussion-between-azamat-rasulov-and-thedexter).